Necessity for rolling
What exactly is needed for rolling motion in horizontal plane? Is friction must for rolling? Or a simple external horizontal force can accelerate the object from rest?
I read that in circular motion, friction is a must when the path is not curved track. But, I have always wondered about the wheels of such cars, and it got me thinking "is friction REALLY needed for rolling the wheels, or it just eases out the process"?

Do you in fact mean "rolling without slipping" when you write "rolling"?

It is really needed, did you ever try to drive on ice?

At a minimum static friction is needed to initiate rolling

The condition for rolling without slipping is simply that $v=r\omega$. As long as that condition is met then there is rolling without slipping.

Is friction must for rolling?

Not technically. It is technically possible to roll without slipping on a frictionless surface. For example, for a car sliding forward on a frictionless surface it would be possible to use the engine to spin the tires to exactly the right speed to match the velocity so that the wheel would be rolling without slipping. This would be rather "artificial" rolling without slipping, and any perturbation would initiate slipping.

I read that in circular motion, friction is a must when the path is not curved track

This sounds like you were reading about turning, not rolling.
